# UITableView not reloading after data being passed in

Tags: uitableview

I know there's a ton of similar questions on here but I reviewed a bunch and am still stuck. Can someone look over my code and see if they can find a reason why the UITableView methods are not being called. I've checked the array and it is being populated but when I call reloadData on the table, nothing.

The process is I am making a SOAP call to get the data, parse the returned XML into a dictionary (each entry is an array of store info) and then pass that to the view controller for the table. I then loop through the dictionary, get each array, get store name and place that in a dataPointTitles array. That's the datasource for my table. Delegates are set. When the app inits I get a count of 0 on the datasource which is correct since no data has been loaded yet. Once the user retrieves data the dataPointTitles array gets populated (see console log printout below) but none of the methods get fired.

Here's my code:

.h file:

```
@interface DataController : UIViewController  <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{ 

NSMutableDictionary* dataDict;
NSMutableArray* dataPointTitles;

UILabel* lblDataLabel;
UITableView* tblDataTable;

SoapController* soapManager; 

ColorController* colorManager;

MKMapView* thisMap; 
CLPlacemark* thisPlaceMark;



}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary* dataDict;

- (void) parseData; 

- (void) setDataDict : (NSMutableDictionary* ) passedDict;

@end
```

relevant parts of the .m file

```
#import "DataController.h"

@interface DataController ()



@end

@implementation DataController

@synthesize dataDict;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//color manager
colorManager = [ColorController new];

//add data label
lblDataLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 40.0, 300.0, 30.0)];
[lblDataLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[lblDataLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size: 12]];
[lblDataLabel setText:@"Local Medicare Providers and Services:"];
[lblDataLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

//add the table 
tblDataTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10.0, 70.0, 300.0, 300.0)];
tblDataTable.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
tblDataTable.separatorColor = [colorManager setColor:176.0:196.0:222.0];
tblDataTable.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
tblDataTable.rowHeight = 20.0;
tblDataTable.scrollEnabled = YES;
tblDataTable.delegate = self;
tblDataTable.dataSource = self;

[self.view addSubview:lblDataLabel];
[self.view addSubview:tblDataTable];

}

- (void) setDataDict : (NSMutableDictionary* ) passedDict {

dataDict = passedDict;
[self parseData];

} 


#pragma mark Parsing Data
- (void) parseData { 

dataPointTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSString* thisObj in dataDict) { 
    NSArray* thisDataSet = [dataDict objectForKey:thisObj];
    [dataPointTitles addObject:[thisDataSet objectAtIndex:1]];
}
NSLog(@"%@", dataPointTitles);
[tblDataTable reloadData];

}

#pragma mark Table Management
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
NSLog(@"%i", [dataPointTitles count]);
return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [dataPointTitles count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tableCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:66.0/255.0 green:66.0/255.0 blue:66.0/255.0 alpha:1];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size: 13.0];
cell.textLabel.text = [dataPointTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

CGRect cellFrame = [cell frame];
cellFrame.size.height = 50.0;

return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString* thisDataPointTitle = [dataPointTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

for(NSString* thisObj in dataDict) { 

    NSArray* thisDataPoint = [dataDict objectForKey:thisObj];

    if ([thisDataPoint objectAtIndex:1] == thisDataPointTitle) { 

    }
}
}
```

Here's the console.log output from the parseData method:

```
"PASSAVANT DEVELOPMENT CORPORATION",
"MYERS DRUG STORE INC",
"WAL-MART STORES EAST LP",
"JAMES GRANT MCGINNESS",
"WAL-MART STORES EAST INC",
"WILLIAM J DIMINO",
"SUBURBAN EYE CARE OPTOMETRIC",
"CMMC INC",
"FOR EYES OPTICAL CO INC",
"LACONS PHARMACY INC",
"PASSAVANT DEVELOPMENT CORPORATION",
"WAL-MART STORES EAST LP",
"RITE AID CORPORATION",
"JAMES GRANT MCGINNESS",
"ABLE MEDICAL EQUIPMENT",
"GIANT FOOD STORES LLC",
"WALGREEN CO",
"ACCESS CARE INC",
"RITE AID CORPORATION",
"CVS DEKALB NORRISTOWN INC",
"FS-PHILADELPHIA LLC",
"DRUG EMPORIUM INC",
"PAUL D HALPERN OD",
"HARRY W FIRTH  JR",
"ABLE MEDICAL EQUIPMENT",
"ACME MARKETS INC DE",
"BROWN'S CH LLC",
"THE MEDICINE SHOPPE",
"MYERS DRUG STORE INC",
"NCS HEALTHCARE OF PENNSYVANIA INC",
"ACCESS CARE INC",
"NORMATEC INC",
"WAL-MART STORES EAST LP",
"COLE VISION CORPORATION",
"RESTORATIVE INNOVATIONS INC",
"ABLE MEDICAL EQUIPMENT",
"CMMC INC",
"KMART OF PENNSYLVANIA LP",
"WAL-MART STORES EAST LP",
"THERESE C DESCHENES OD PC",
"ALLEN SOFFER OD PC",
"WAL-MART STORES EAST INC",
"RITE AID CORPORATION",
"NORRISTOWN CVS INC",
"WAL-MART STORES EAST LP",
"FOR EYES OPTICAL CO INC",
"LACONS PHARMACY INC"
```

Comment: In `parseData`, can you also log the value of `tblDataTable` and `tblDataTable.dataSource`?

Comment: I get null for each...I could see the datasource being null, but why the table?

Comment: Any chance `parseData` is being called before `viewDidLoad` (or that you have two different `DataController` objects)?  Otherwise, I'd be tempted to make `tblDataTable` a strong property, force all updates to go through the 'setter', and try to track where it's being changed.

Comment: I'll double check my code for a duplicate DC obj. parseData only gets called after the viewDidLoad.

Comment: The only other thing that comes to mind is automatic setting of weak references to nil in ARC but it doesn't look like you're doing that in what you posted....

Comment: Phillip, make the duplicate DC obj your answer and I will select it as the right one. That was the problem. I'm expanding an app and missed that. Good call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments: apparently we have a problem with more than one `DataController` object being involved in the logic and causing some confusion in the parsing/view-loading.